# Email Confirmation Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email

I have seen a lot of Examples where a users Confirmed registration is done through using a token generated through WebSecurity that is linked to simple membership but in order to take control of my own code I have wrote a lot of the user registration and logins from scratch using entity framework for DB access rather than trying to fight against tedious auto generated templates that give me no breakdown as to what is going on and that give me no confidence as to what is going on.  I have to be honest that is how I feel about them as they don't show any code as to how the user db interacts with any of the custom functions I write.

So my query is has anyone used a custom token for email validation that does not have to use the websecurity.CreateAccount Method before?

I would have to do some amount of refactoring for already perfectly sound and functional code that it would be a shame.  Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Has anyone used a custom token for email validation that does not have to use the websecurity.CreateAccount Method before?

Absolutely - we do this for all of our email verification tokens, which is part of our "CreateAccount" process. You could do something like this to generate the tokens :

```
public static string GenerateEmailToken()
{
    // generate an email verification token for the user
    using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider provider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[16];
        provider.GetBytes(data);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
    }
}
```

I then include that in our "CreateAccountResponse", which allows the controller to pick it up and send the verification email with the token included - to give you an idea:

```
public class CreateAccountResponse
{
    public bool CreatedSuccessfully { get; set; }

    public string EmailVerificationToken { get; set; }
}
```

And then we handle that here:

```
CreateAccountResponse response = _mediator.Send(createAccountCommand);

if (response.CreatedSuccessfully)
{   
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.EmailVerificationToken))
    {
        // Send the verification email if a token is present
        SendVerificationEmail(model.Email, response.EmailVerificationToken);
    }       

    return RedirectToAction("Settings", "Account");
}
```

Then using the token, we create the fully formatted URL to include in the email you send to this user

```
private void SendVerificationEmail(string emailAddress, string token)
{
    try
    {
        // Url.Action will encode parameters as they are needed.
        var verificationUrl = Url.Action("VerifyAccount", "Account", new { token = token }, Request.Url.Scheme);
        _userMailer.DeliverVerification(emailAddress, verificationUrl);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.ErrorLog.Log(new VerificationError(ex));
    }
}
```

Once they click the link in the email, our "VerifyAccount" route picks up the token and allows us to complete the rest of the verification process.

Also, it's a *very good* idea to set an **expiration** for your verification tokens for security purposes - 24 to 48 hours is usually an acceptable time frame to allow the user to receive the email, click the link, and verify their account.

Comment: This is the clarification I was looking for . fantastic thanks a mill. At least now I know I can store a token with my users table by looking at that model. The examples I look at completly overlooks any of the more fundamental questions I have as to how some of the framework methods validate and handle issues like this. The reason I thought it would be good to ask here was that I was talking to another developer in Java that sometimes it is no harm to write cutom logic just so you are not completely dependant on all framework methods and lose control of what I am  doing. Many thanks :)

Comment: No problem, glad that helped. Since this answered your question, you should mark it as the Accepted Answer.